# ElasticSearch date range query returns incorrect results

Tags: elasticsearch

Using the following date range query includes results that are outside of the date range we wish to filter by.

```
{
   "query" : {

         "range" : {
           "account.expiry" : {
             "gte" : "2016-03-03T00:00:00.000Z",
             "lt" : "2017-03-02T00:00:00.000Z"
           }
         }
   },
   "_source" : {
     "includes" : [ "account.expiry"],
     "excludes" : [ ]
   }

 }
```

I have tried various different variations (using 'to' and 'from' instead of 'gt' and 'lte').

I've checked the mappings of the index and they look OK to me (Elastic doesn't see the field as a string).  Here's the relevant part:

```
{
    "myindex.dev": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "account": {
                "properties": {
                    "account": {
                        "properties": {
                            "expiry": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I've written a unit test that spins up an ES locally and populates it with data, and this doesn't seem to have the same problem.  I've checked and they're both using the same version of ElasticSearch.  Running the test from a different JRE doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'd appreciate any help you can give!

Edit:

These are the results I am getting from this query.  I'm working on steps to reproduce but it seems to be behaving when running on my own  machine

```
(
    {
    "took": 9,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 3,
        "successful": 3,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 13234,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "accounts.dev",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "4328398",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "account": {
                        "expiry": "2012-09-30T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "accounts.dev",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "7504549",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "account": {
                        "expiry": "2012-09-30T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "accounts.dev",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "8333546",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "account": {
                        "expiry": "2012-09-30T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "accounts.dev",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "12693814",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "account": {
                        "expiry": "2012-09-30T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "accounts.dev",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "32583326",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "account": {
                        "expiry": "2012-09-30T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "accounts.dev",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "66828717",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "account": {
                        "expiry": "2013-09-07T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "accounts.dev",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "66905991",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "account": {
                        "expiry": "2013-11-25T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "accounts.dev",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "12843517",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "account": {
                        "expiry": "2016-02-23T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "accounts.dev",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "43597281",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "account": {
                        "expiry": "2013-06-12T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "accounts.dev",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "43597291",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "account": {
                        "expiry": "2012-12-31T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

In response to the comment, yes actually there is a nested expiry field in the source document too... it looks like this.

```
 "account": {
    "permissionSets": [
        {
            "expiry": "2013-10-29T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "expiry": "2016-09-30T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "expiry": "2012-09-30T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "expiry": "2012-09-30T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ],
    "expiry": "2012-09-30T00:00:00Z"
```

Comment: Can you paste some sample document also where we can recreate the situation

Comment: Please include a portion of a sample document that is being returned by the query that you don't believe ought to be.

Comment: I've added the search results - hopefully that will help.  Anything else, please ask.  I haven't been able to recreate the situation on another machine myself but am working on doing so so that I can provide what you're after.

Comment: Pure speculation but would it be possible that there is another `expiry` field at a different nested level of account type . You could check it by viewing  the entire source document  instead of only a single field.

Comment: Your documents show an index of "accounts.dev", whereas your mapping shows an index of "myindex.dev". Any chance "accounts.dev" has a different mapping for `account.expiry`?

Comment: @BrookeB my apologies this was a typo, be assured that the index has a consistent name.

Comment: @keety I think you may be on to something - I've updated my question with the information - but I do have some nested expiry fields!  Can these be ignored from the query?